# All of sudden Specflow generator is throwing exception with Visual studio 2015.I have not upgraded any new package of Visual Studio or Specflow

Tags: specflow

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Specflow 2017.1..12. I have been using this combination for more than 2 years. Everything was fine until January 2018.

We did not develop any new test in February 2018. As we did not get time to work on automation. I started working on new tests since last week and updating existing tests. When I modified existing specflow feature file and save it, the `feature.cs` file is not getting generated. It is throwing a generator exception.

I am not sure why we are getting this exception all of sudden. We did not upgrade any Visual Studio or Specflow plugin for more than 1 year.

I have been searching online for a solution, but I could find any answer. Please help!

This is the generator exception:

```
#error TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Interfaces.TestGenerationError
#error TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator
#error Server stack trace: 
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginLoader.LoadPlugin(PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3.<LoadPlugins>b__1(PluginDescriptor pd)
#error    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
#error    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__58`1.MoveNext()
#error    at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
#error    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(ObjectContainer container, IGeneratorConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.TestGeneratorFactory.CreateGenerator(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
#error    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
#error    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
#error Exception rethrown at [0]: 
#error    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
#error    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Interfaces.ITestGeneratorFactory.CreateGenerator(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.IdeIntegration.Generator.RemoteAppDomainTestGeneratorFactory.CreateGenerator(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.IdeIntegration.Generator.GeneratorServices.CreateTestGenerator()
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.IdeIntegration.Generator.IdeSingleFileGenerator.GenerateCode(String inputFilePath, String inputFileContent, GeneratorServices generatorServices, ProjectSettings projectSettings)
#error    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.IdeIntegration.Generator.IdeSingleFileGenerator.Generate(String inputFilePath, String inputFileContent, GeneratorServices generatorServices, CodeDomHelper codeDomHelper, ProjectSettings projectSettings)
```